# Error $.ajax not a function?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I try to call `ajax` but get this error:

> $.ajax not a function

https://jsfiddle.net/q79pbn7t/4/

By the way, `ajax` working for the others class. What errors can be happen?

This is my code

```
<button onclick="sendEmail()">hihi</button>
<script>
  function sendEmail() {
    email = 'email'
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "email",
      data: {
        email: email
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data)
      }
    })
    alert(1)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Where you have included the jquery library file

Answer (score 2):

You first need to include jQuery in order to have `$` and `$.ajax`.

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/6fqrLbzd/).

Comment: where is JQuery you put?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code that uses jQuery into:

```
$(function() {
  // Your code, ajax calls, etc.
});
```